# Having hard time with Angular2 RxJS usage

Tags: angular, webpack, rxjs, angular-cli

I am trying to build a simple service to retrieve some data:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import {UtilsService} from "./../../util/util.service";
import {LoginResult} from "./LoginResult";

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
  private url:string = this.utilsService.getBaseRestUrl() + "ad/authentication-service/login";

  constructor(private http:Http, private utilsService:UtilsService) {
  }

  login(user:Object):Observable<LoginResult> {
    return this.http
      .get(this.url)
      .map(response => response.json().data as LoginResult);
  }
}
```

But I cannot get the thing working, because this import: `import 'rxjs/operator/map';` seems not to get resolved. I use IntelliJ and get an `unresolved function or method error`.

When I try to run the web console writes: `ReferenceError: LoginService is not defined` - obviously because of this unresolved function.

When I navigate to node_modules I can find the `map.js` containing the needed function. I use Angular cli so I don't have any 'system JS config' because Angular Cli is based on the Webpack.

How can I tell Webpack where the function is defined? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: where did you provide LoginService ?

Comment: I've got a LoginComponent where I provide it `providers: [LoginService]`

Comment: so you think it's the map that cause the issue. Did you try with promise ?

Comment: This can happen if `rxjs` package is duplicated, so Http uses a different copy which is not affected by `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'`. You can test if it's true by wrapping it with another observable, `Observable.from(this.http.get(...)) .map(...)`.

Comment: Since we dont have all your files, it would be great if you follow the angular-seed project https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed, which is using webpack and you should be able to easily track what you are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem - here is solution:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Headers, Http, Response} from '@angular/http';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

import {LoginResult} from './login.result';
import {UtilsService} from './../../util/util.service'

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
  private url:string;

  constructor(private http: Http, utilsService: UtilsService) {
    this.url = utilsService.getBaseRestUrl() + "ad/authentication-service/login";
  }

  login(user:Object):Observable<LoginResult> {
    return this.http.post(this.url, user)
      .map((r: Response) => r.json() as LoginResult)
      .catch(LoginService.handleError);
  }

  private static handleError(error: any): Observable<any> {
    console.log('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
    return Observable.throw(error.json().message || 'Server error');
  }
}
```

Problem was in using another service:

```
private url:string = this.utilsService.getBaseRestUrl()
```

The `utilsService` was obviously undefined, so I moved it to the constructor and added service to the Components providers array: `providers: [LoginService, UtilsService]`.

App starts without arrors.

Answer (score 1):

I used the angular-cli and generated my app and it is working as expected.

Please try the below and let me know if this works.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs';//Removed:/Observable
//import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import {UtilsService} from "./../../util/util.service";
import {LoginResult} from "./LoginResult";

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
  private url:string = this.utilsService.getBaseRestUrl() + "ad/authentication-service/login";

  constructor(private http:Http, private utilsService:UtilsService) {
  }

  login(user:Object):Observable<LoginResult> {
    return this.http
      .get(this.url)
      .map((r: Response) => r.json() as LoginResult);
  }
}
```

Here is the example service you may use it,
https://github.com/reflexdemon/shop/blob/master/src/app/user.service.ts

Please feel free to use the code as it was created for learning angular2.

https://github.com/reflexdemon/shop

Comment: Thx for the usefull links